# Is it ok to keep the "old" version of my program in a branch?

Tags: git, branch, versioning

I maintain a program which version is "1.x", on `master` branch. Now I'm planning a big rewrite of it, so most of the files will be deleted/replaced with new ones, but main functionalities will remain the same. I want to call it version "2.x".

I don't want to create a new repository for it (example, I would lose all the open issues of 1.x that I want to address in 2.x). Instead, I was thinking to:

- Branch the master to a temporary `2.x-dev` and start making disruptive changes there
- When "2.x" is ready, create a branch `1.x` from the current master.
- Merge `2.x-dev` into `master`.

At the end, master will suddenly become the "2.x" version of the program, while "1.x" will remain on a branch that **will never be merged into master**.

Is it a good practice or should I do it in another way?

EDIT: I'm not 100% sure I won't make further changes to `1.x` after the merge. Example 1.x might remain for somekind of retrocompatibility. But it won't receive any new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you plan further development in your `1.x` line? If so, a branch is exactly right. (Due to the nature of the *DAG* – the *directed acyclic graph* – there is only a semantic difference between a "fork" and a "branch". Think of a fork simply as a "remote branch" on a different server).

If `1.x` is just the historical record and will never be modified again, use a tag (command: `git tag`) instead.

But you can even combine the two:

- Create a tag `1.0` to mark the specific version of your latest 1.x release.
- If you see the need to do further work, create new branch from the tag: `git checkout -b 1.x 1.0`.

If you release a new 1.x release, simply tag the latest state of your branch again: `git tag 1.1 1.x`

Comment: I've edited the question with the answer for you: I'm not 100% sure of it :)

Comment: @TheUnexpected I have extended my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it does! Can I do also the opposite? First I branch 1.x, then when I'll be sure I won't touch it anymore, tag is as "1.x", then delete the branch?

Comment: @TheUnexpected Sure, that's basically my last sentence (`git tag 1.1 1.x`). Git is flexible and doesn't impose any order on your workflow. Use whatever works for your workflow.

Comment: I feel like you can just delete the first two paragraphs. Instead of guessing, just always tag each version. Then anytime you need further development on a version, create the branch the moment development begins.